# Finding quartile using .apply in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am passing a column called petrol['tax'] of a dataframe to a function using .apply which returns 1st quartile. I am trying to use the below code but it throws me this error 'float' object has no attribute 'quantile'.

```
def Quartile(petrol_attrib):
    return petrol_attrib.quantile(.25)

petrol['tax'].apply(Quartile)
```

I need help to implement this.

Comment: Oops that was quantile. There is [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

Comment: I need to know if petrol['tax'].quartile(.25) is possible and why cant this is not possible petrol_attrib.quantile(.25) ? Because the same petrol['tax'] column only i am passing as argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 10], [3, 100], [4, 100]]),
                  columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Now you can  use the quantile function  in pandas. Make sure you using the numbers between 0 and 1. Here an example below:

```
 df.a.quantile(0.5)
 3.25

You can apply the function to the whole dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quartile function on a data frame, not series. You can use the same method by writing `petrol[['tax']]` instead of `petrol['tax']`. The version below is the modified one:

```
def Quartile(petrol_attrib):
    return petrol_attrib.quantile(.25)

petrol[['tax']].apply(Quartile)
```

Comment: Please format any code in your answer posts using the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

The apply function serializes the object that is passed to it and performs the function on each element individually. You can call `quantile()` on a DataFrame or a Series (unlike some other answers have stated) but you can't call it on a float. You are effectively trying to call `quantile()` on *every element of the Series*, since each element in the series is a float and `.quantile()` doesn't work on floats, that's why you are getting an error.

I recommend simply calling `petrol['tax'].quantile(.25)` directly. However, if you prefer to keep your custom function, just pass the Series to it directly rather than using `.apply()`: `Quartile(petrol['tax'])`